# How do I detect an animated GIF's ticks per second?

Tags: php, linux, imagemagick, gif

I'm looking for a way to detect the (average) frame rate of an animated GIF using Linux. PHP's Imagick class seems to provide this functionality but I rather avoid installing a ton of libraries to get it to work.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-getimagetickspersecond.php

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: How is one library "a ton?"

Comment: @Bears: It's a little known fact that the imagemagick library weighs roughly 2,106 lbs (when the source code is printed out on heavyweight 8.5x11in paper in 12-pt with 1" margins on each side ;-)

Comment: @Josh: single-sided printing or double? What font? _INKJET OR LASER???_ GET WITH IT MAN!

Comment: @Bears I believe I'd also need libmagick9-dev which is a bit dependency heavy (74 packages in total).

Comment: I kind of doubt that, seeing as libmagick9-dev looks a helluva lot like a dev library - "This package includes header files and static libraries needed to compile programs using libMagick." [source](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/libmagick9-dev)

Comment: @Bears I was following instructions here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php#83715. @Pekka's solution seems simpler so I'll go with that.

Comment: @ElbertF: `libmagick9-dev` is only needed if you want to recompile PHP with `libmagick` support yourself, or write a compiled program that uses `libmagick`.  If you just want to use your distribution's existing PHP `libmagick` support, it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think ImageMagick really is your best bet.

This is what a `identify filename.gif` on an animated GIF looks like:

```
gif.gif[1] GIF 350x350 350x350+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 256c 145KB 0.000u 0:00.003
gif.gif[2] GIF 350x350 350x350+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 256c 145KB 0.000u 0:00.006
gif.gif[3] GIF 350x350 350x350+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 256c 145KB 0.000u 0:00.010
```

this doesn't give you the frame rate - which is *good*, because animated GIFs don't have a global frame rate, they have an individual one between frames.

Comment: Even better! This is what I was after.

Answer (score 6):

You can customize the info format of what ImageMagick's `identify` should display to you:

```
identify \
      -format "%T ticks:  %f: Frame[%s]  %m %wx%h %P%O %r %z-bit\n" \
       anim.gif
```

That should do the trick.

**Example output:**

```
 50 ticks:  anim.gif: Frame[0]  GIF 128x128 128x128+0+0 PseudoClass sRGB Matte 8-bit
 10 ticks:  anim.gif: Frame[1]  GIF 128x128 128x128+0+0 PseudoClass sRGB Matte 8-bit
 10 ticks:  anim.gif: Frame[2]  GIF 128x128 128x128+0+0 PseudoClass sRGB Matte 8-bit
 10 ticks:  anim.gif: Frame[3]  GIF 128x128 128x128+0+0 PseudoClass sRGB Matte 8-bit
 10 ticks:  anim.gif: Frame[4]  GIF 128x128 128x128+0+0 PseudoClass sRGB Matte 8-bit
 50 ticks:  anim.gif: Frame[5]  GIF 128x128 128x128+0+0 PseudoClass sRGB Matte 8-bit
 10 ticks:  anim.gif: Frame[6]  GIF 1x1 128x128+0+0 PseudoClass sRGB Matte 8-bit
 10 ticks:  anim.gif: Frame[7]  GIF 128x128 128x128+0+0 PseudoClass sRGB Matte 8-bit
 10 ticks:  anim.gif: Frame[8]  GIF 128x128 128x128+0+0 PseudoClass sRGB Matte 8-bit
 10 ticks:  anim.gif: Frame[9]  GIF 128x128 128x128+0+0 PseudoClass sRGB Matte 8-bit
 10 ticks:  anim.gif: Frame[10]  GIF 128x128 128x128+0+0 PseudoClass sRGB Matte 8-bit
```