# how do I use Imagemagick to determine the framerate of a GIF?

Tags: imagemagick, gif, frame-rate

I am using Imagemagick to turn a gif into a corresponding series of jpgs and I am trying to determine when each jpg happens in a series.

stolen from [How do I detect an animated GIF's ticks per second?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588658/how-do-i-detect-an-animated-gifs-ticks-per-second): `identify  -format "%T ticks:  %f: Frame[%s]  %m %wx%h %P%O %r %z-bit\n" tree.gif`

```
4 ticks:  tree.gif: Frame[0]  GIF 247x175 247x175+0+0 PseudoClassRGBMatte 8-bit
4 ticks:  tree.gif: Frame[1]  GIF 247x175 247x175+0+0 PseudoClassRGBMatte 8-bit
4 ticks:  tree.gif: Frame[2]  GIF 247x175 247x175+0+0 PseudoClassRGBMatte 8-bit
4 ticks:  tree.gif: Frame[3]  GIF 247x175 247x175+0+0 PseudoClassRGBMatte 8-bit
4 ticks:  tree.gif: Frame[4]  GIF 247x175 247x175+0+0 PseudoClassRGBMatte 8-bit
4 ticks:  tree.gif: Frame[5]  GIF 247x175 247x175+0+0 PseudoClassRGBMatte 8-bit
```

and `identify tree.gif` gives me

```
tree.gif[0] GIF 247x175 247x175+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 256c 1.923MB 0.000u 0:00.000
tree.gif[1] GIF 247x175 247x175+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 256c 1.923MB 0.000u 0:00.000
tree.gif[2] GIF 247x175 247x175+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 256c 1.923MB 0.000u 0:00.000
tree.gif[3] GIF 247x175 247x175+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 256c 1.923MB 0.000u 0:00.000
tree.gif[4] GIF 247x175 247x175+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 256c 1.923MB 0.000u 0:00.010
tree.gif[5] GIF 247x175 247x175+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 256c 1.923MB 0.000u 0:00.010
tree.gif[6] GIF 247x175 247x175+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 256c 1.923MB 0.000u 0:00.010
...
```

can anyone translate this output that will tell me either the framerate or when each frame appears?  Extra points if you can make it work using RMagick.

Answer (score 11):

There are complications. First of all, you need to use the `%T` and `%s` escapes to look at the frame number and the delay (in **centiseconds**), not the vanilla `identify` command. Second, the delay from one frame to the next varies, so you need to be prepared to deal with cases when your animated GIF does not have a unified "frame rate" from end to end.

Here is an example command: `identify -format "Frame %s: %Tcs\n" A.gif`

For more info:

1. http://imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/
2. http://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php